# Make a view highlightable in a linearlayout

Tags: android

I wish to make views highlighted like items in a listview(I use linearlayout instead because listview cannot use addchild() to dynamically add new items)

When a listview item is touched,the item is usually highlight green.How do I implement this feature into views in a linearlayout?

I tried view.requestfocus in the view's ontouchlistener.this returns true but nothing can be observed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add items to a listview dynamically....

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

/** Items entered by the user is stored in this ArrayList variable */
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

/** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Setting a custom layout for the list activity */
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /** Reference to the button of the layout main.xml */
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    /** Defining the ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    /** Defining a click event listener for the button "Add" */
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                               
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            list.add(edit.getText().toString());
            edit.setText("");               
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    /** Setting the event listener for the add button */
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

    /** Setting the adapter to the ListView */
    setListAdapter(adapter);        
}
```

}

Comment: thank you for offering me another solution.this is absolutely helpful!but i still would like to know how highlighting is implemented.